# Creating an automated build fails due to a so called missing namespace

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I am really new to TFS 2010 automated builds.

I am trying to setup an automated build for a project I am working on. Locally if I build the project it compiles as I expect it to without any errors.

If I trigger my build definition the build fails telling me that one of my .cs files is missing a namespace for a referenced project.

I have checked the reference and it's set to copy local, is there another reason why my build server doesn't think that the .dll is there?

Any pointers would be great!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is that you are referencing a DLL that you have on your local machine, but that doesn't exist on the build server.  My suggestion is looking at the build server build log and looking for any build warnings about unable to find references.

Chances are you need to add the DLL's to TFS and update the project references to reference the relative path in the source tree.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, Thanks Dylan.

Comment: I had a similar issue - the build server was looking for a local `*.resx` file which was already removed (deleted) from the project but still being referenced in the build server's solution file (`*.sln`). It helped in my case to edit the build definition, remove the solution, re-add the solution and then queue the build: After that it succeeded again. **Note** that the project **did** compile successfully on my local PC, but not on the build server - although everything was checked in correctly. I hope this comment helps some of you having a similar issue.